# How to monitor cloud system metrics through grafana

Tags: grafana, jmeter, telegraf

I have a system configured with telegraf + InfluxDB + Grafana in one machine.

Now i need to collect server metrics for ubuntu servers which is deployed in cloud and need to plot in grafana.

My question here is :

1. Can i collect the metrics through telegraf itself ? if yes then do i need to install telegraf in all the cloud servers to pull the metrics ?
2. Is there any other way to pull the metrics from aws cloud servers and store it in the central influxdb database ?
3. Is it possible to perform it through any other plugins available in jmeter itself ?

Thanks In Advance for the valuable comments.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes you can and yes you need to install the [telegraf agent](https://docs.influxdata.com/telegraf/v1.12/introduction/getting-started/) on each server you want to monitor
2. There are other ways of collecting server performance data:

   - [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/), in this case you will need to install [PerfMon Server Agent](https://github.com/undera/perfmon-agent) onto all servers
   - [SSHMon Samples Collector](https://github.com/tilln/jmeter-sshmon#sshmon-samples-collector-), you will not need to install any software onto servers, however you will need to have [SSH](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/protocol/) connectivity with all servers you want to monitor
3. I'm not aware of any existing plugins, however you can come up with your own implementation of the [AbstractBackendListenerClient](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/visualizers/backend/AbstractBackendListenerClient.html) which will be sending server-side performance metrics to InfluxDB